# Django - Cannot find URL "Using the URLconf defined in contactform.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order"

Tags: python, django

I am able to successfully compile my program, but when I go to the localhost address, it gives me an error. I have searched other forums about the same problem, but I couldn't find a solution for mine. Am I missing something here? I'm new to Django, so any is appreciated.

```
Using the URLconf defined in contactform.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/

showform

The empty path didn’t match any of these.
```

**settings.py:**

```html
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'contact.apps.ContactConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'contactform.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'contactform.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'userInfo',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        }
    }
}
```

**apps.py**

```html
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ContactConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'contact'
```

**manage.py**

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'contactform.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**view.py**

```html
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import FormContactForm


def showform(request):
    form = FormContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'contactform.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from contact import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('showform', views.showform),
]
```

Comment: You don't have any url patterns serving the empty path, try going to `http://localhost:8000/showform`?

Comment: @IainShelvington After trying to redirect there, I get an error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /showform

And in my terminal it says there's no template for contactform.html. But I do have the form in my file tree in the same level as views.py

Comment: Create a templates folder in your contacts app `contact/templates` and move the template there - `contact/templates/contactform.html`

Comment: @IainShelvington That was it.. Thank you so much!! Was looking for a problem in my code for a while